# cURL call with a port in the url/location not working - couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am trying to make a cURL call to a url that looks like this:

https://example.com:9000/test

When I execute the following code, I get curl error 7 couldn't connect to host.

```
$headers = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com:9000/test',
);
$headers[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
$headers[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

If I set the url to `https://example.com/test`, I am able to connect to the host, just not to what I need to get.

I have also tried setting `<code>CURLOPT_PORT => 9000</code>` with the same result (error 7).

One other note, I am able to use cURL with the url on some machines but not others. My Windows machine works fine, but the linux server I'm on is the one having issues. Another linux server seems to work fine as well.

EDIT:
Server is shared hosting on `hostgator.com`.

Comment: How could I check that? I have shared hosting on hostgator.com.

Comment: If you have shell access, try `telnet example.com 9000` and see if that times out. If it does, it's not a curl problem, and something to do with the network configuration.

Comment: @marc-b Result of the telnet call: Name or service not known. I'm not familiar with telnet at all so not sure where to begin on fixing this.

Comment: Then `example.com` is not resolving on that machine. `host example.com` and/or `nslookup example.com` will probably report "no such/unknown host". So most likely it's a DNS error. Check what the resolver settings are on the "bad" server compared to the "working" ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, contact your server host. I contacted hostgator.com and they responded with the following:

> I have opened the outbound port 9000
>   for you.

Everything works now.

Comment: You can get them to open a port for you, or just use one of these ports: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/commonly-used-port-numbers

Answer (score 0):

check the url in IE browser. if it works fine then remove the timeout params and try.

Comment: So it works fine in the browser. Like I stated in the original post, it also is working fine on a couple of systems, just not on one server that is hosted by http://hostgator.com. The request immediately comes back as couldn't connect to host, so I think that it's some type of server setup.

Comment: Removed the timeout parameters and the result was the exact same. Also ran `curl -k -L http://example.com:9000/test` from command line with the same error.

Comment: after curl_exec() function add $report=curl_getinfo($ch); and print and check the output. you can get some info from that..

Comment: and check the returned data with http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/07/errors-in-curl-returned-by-curlgetinfo.html i have added the error codes with its description.

Comment: error code is 0: `Array ( [url] => https://example.com:9000/test [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.187683 [namelookup_time] => 0.187477 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 )`