# file_get_contents and port 8000

Tags: php, port, file-get-contents

On my 'ipage' page, when I use file_get_contents on a url with port 8000, I don't get anything.

Like :

```
$geturl = file_get_contents('http://mfpradio.no-ip.org:8000/status.xsl');
print_r($geturl);
```

This is working locally.

'ipage' doesn't even read the script after 'print_r'.
It works with, for example :

```
$geturl = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

I've tried curl, same issue.

I can play my stream on my 'ipage' page.

So it looks like 'ipage' is blocking port '8000' for `file_get_contents()`.
Is it normal that webshost do that?

Comment: Don't really know what's normal, but you might contact your host's support to ask them what ports they allow communication on.

Comment: Have you tried using fsockopen() and similar functions?

Comment: The answer is there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586981/curl-call-with-a-port-in-the-url-location-not-working-couldnt-connect-to-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has an option to block the file handling functions from working over a URL. This option is often switched on by hosting companies for security reasons.

Find out what the setting of this flag is -- use something like `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` to find out whether it's allowed. My guess is that it'll be set not to allow it.

If it isn't allowed by the host, then you will have to use an alternative method (and probably more complex) to read the data. The usual answer there is to use CURL (although it can be quite long-winded code. plus it's possible for the CURL extension also not to be available)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `CURL`?

Are you sure the server can reach that page? It should work with domain.com:port

Comment: Yes, the server can reach it. The server can play the stream there, and it reach if with a link. I  tried curl. Works locally, and works in 'ipage' if the link doesn't have port 8000.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure server http://mfpradio.no-ip.org:8000/ port i.e. 8000 is **open on your server firewall as outgoing port** to read page information…

file_get_contents() try to read page content from that port :)